Rama Doota to Sri Lanka
Too simple a question to ask..
In Ramayana who is the ambassador sent by Rama to Ravana before the war? Angada as in the Hindi movie (Ramanand Sagar)  or  Hanuman as in the Telugu movie as well as in what is commonly known in the Valmiki Ramayana?
